# Задача массивы Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = [ [1,2,3,4,5],
      [6,7,8,9,10], 
      [11,12,13,14,15] 
      ]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][j])
```

Реализовал перебор списка в списке слева направо, как можно переписать и перебирать справа налево? Чтобы вывелось 5 4 3 2 1 10 9 8 7 6

Comment: [5-j] или range(len(a[i])-1, 0,-1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

способ 1:

```
arr = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
]

for line in arr:
    print(*reversed(line), end=' ')
```

способ 2:

```
for line in arr:
    for i in range(len(line)):
        print(line[len(line) - i - 1], end=' ')
```

способ 3 (по сути тот же способ 1):

```
for line in arr:
    for value in reversed(line):
        print(value, end=' ')
```

способ 4 (тоже по сути способ 1):

```
for line in arr:
    for value in line[::-1]:
        print(value, end=' ')
```

способ 5 (все тот же способ 1):

```
for line in arr:
    print(*line[::-1], end=' ')
```

способ 6 (по сути способ 2, только без излишеств):

```
for line in arr:
    for i in range(len(line)):
        print(line[-i - 1], end=' ')
```

Comment: Как всегда, все способы, а что мне писать теперь??? ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
a = [ [1,2,3,4,5],
      [6,7,8,9,10], 
      [11,12,13,14,15] 
      ]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[i])):
        print(a[i][len(a[i])-j-1])
```

например...

Comment: место [len(a[i])-j-1] можно писать `[-j-1]`

Comment: @Danis Да задача-то учебная... в такой форме оно будет наиболее понятно имхо.